# Extract certain data from two files and put these together in one file - unix command

Tags: unix

I have a directory "dir_ling" with a list of files:

```
file_i.cnf
file_i.cnf.out
```

for 0 < i < n.

An example of the file_i.cnf is

```
p cnf 8308 33032
c clauses-vars: 3.975927
1 -2 -3 0
-1 2 0
-1 3 0
4 -5 -3 0
```

An example of the file_i.cnf.out is

```
[7.03] thread-stats node:0/1 thread:0/1 props:10733141 decs:23093 confs:22488 mem:3.03
[7.03] node-stats node:0/1 solved:1 res:10 props:10733141 decs:23093 confs:22488 mem:3.03 shared:0 filtered:0
[7.03] glob-stats nodes:1 threads:1 solved:1 res:10 rounds:8 time:7.00 mem:3.03 MB props:1533080.49 decs:3298.52 confs:3212.10 shared:0.00 imported:0.00 filtered:0.00 dropped:0.00
```

I need a command with input "dir_ling" and that output the file dir_ling.timescv where each line of this file contains the name of the file with "time:" of the file *.out and with "clauses-vars:" of the file *.cnf; For example dir_ling.timescv will be contain

```
 file_1.cnf 7.00 3.975927
 file_2.cnf 8.00 4.909000
 .
 .
 .
```

I trying with this command

```
 grep "glob-stats" $1/* | grep "solved:1" | tr : " " | cut -d " " -f 1,15 | sed 's/.*\///' | sed 's/\.out//' > solved-$1.times
```

with that command I get

```
 file_1.cnf 7.00
 file_2.cnf 8.00
```

My question is How Can I put the "clauses-vars:" field?

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the files with something like

```
for f in file_*.cnf; do
   firstpart=$(grep "glob-stats" "${f}" | sed 's/.*time:\([^ ]*\).*/\1/')
   secondpart=$(grep "clauses-vars" ${f}.out | cut -d":" -f2)
   echo "$f ${firstpart}${secondpart}"
done
```

The greps, cut and sed can be optimized for what is valid for your files. In my solution I made some assumptions:

- The cnf file has exactly 1 line with glob-stats
  Maybe you want to add `head -1`.
- The line with glog-stats has 1 time field
  I use a `sed` construction with `\(match_this\)` and `\1`.
- The line with ONE clauses-vars has 1 `:` at the right position.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes may not be the easiest way to do that. Assuming variable `$nb` contains the index number of your file, I can print one line with:

```bash
echo file_$nb.cnf \
    $(sed -n '/glob-stats/s/.*time:\([.0-9]*\).*/\1/p' file_$nb.cnf.out) \
    $(sed -n 's/.*clauses-vars: //p' file_$nb.cnf)
```

Then you can put it in a for loop to have `$nb` loop over the indices, and redirect the output into a file.

For the details:

- `-n` option for `sed` means “do not print output unless explicitely asked”.
- The first `sed` command search the first file (`.cnf.out`) for a line containing `glob-stats` and performs a substitution on it, memorizing the digits after `time:` and replacing the whole line by it. Then it prints (`p`) the result of this substitution.
- The second `sed` command erases the beginning of the line containing `clauses-var:` in the second file and prints (`p`) the result.
- Both `sed` commands are used with command substitution (enclosed within `$()`), so that the commands are replaced by their output on the final `echo` command.

Something similar could probably be obtained with `paste` and process substitution (`paste <(echo $filename) <(sed …) <(sed …)`)